# One Cell that fills other cells with data

Tags: excel

What I am trying to do is as following:
Example Image here:

[image: Example Image here]

What I would like is that the cell "ItemNumber" fills in the cells of weight quantity and name.

So if I would pre-define certain itemnumbers with weights, qty's, and names. And I would enter an itemnumber in that table it would automatically show those values there.

What is the fastest and most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Take a look at [`VLOOKUP()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Comment: I will look that up, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use VBA or excel funtion?  If is a pre-define set of combinations, you can use Vlookup funtion for that.

Comment: For me it doesn't really matter. However i think normal Excel function will be more simple? It doens't have to be complex. If i understand correctly, with Vlookup i create a table with all the info and then use Vlookup to put the information from that table into the cells of weight etc?